# Graph of Natural Logarithmic Function

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

If the graph of ln y against ln x is a straight line with gradient 4 and y-intercept 6, find the relationship between x and y.

Here's my approach:

$$ln y = ln x$$

$$e^{lnx} = y$$

However,

$$y = 4x + 6$$

...from the information provided in the question.

Therefore,

$$e^{lnx} = 4x + 6$$

$$lnx = ln (4x+6)$$

$$4x + 6 = x$$

$$3x+6 = 0$$

And this is where I get stuck.

I have a feeling that my approach from the beginning is flawed, but cannot think of another way to interpret the question.

The answer is the following:

$$y = e^6x^4$$

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The graph is between $\ln y$ and $\ln x$ so the equation of the line will be $\ln y=4\ln x+6$.

Comment: Linear in log means $\log(y)=a+b\log(x)$

Answer (score 1):

$\log(y) = 4\log(x) + 6$. Therefore, $\log(y) = \log x^{4} + 6$. From this we get $\log(y/x^{4}) = 6$ From which we get $y = e^{6}x^{4}$